# Elastic beanstalk single instance application with public internet but only my IP to be allowed to access the Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I wanted to create a simple single instance AWS elastic beanstalk application that should be accessible via internet but only via my IP address. I do not need a load balancer for this, but if absolutely required I can have one.

I want to understand what should be the configuration of EC2 security group and Route table etc to achieve such a thing. I did following and got errors in deploying the application, I think because of restrictions I put even the AWS elastic bean / S3 / Cloud watch, nothing in AWS is able to access my EC2 instance, so the application is not coming up, there is no info in health of EB environment etc.
The error in Elastic Beanstalk console log is

```
The EC2 instances failed to communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, either because of configuration problems with the VPC or a failed EC2 instance. Check your VPC configuration and try launching the environment again.
```

I created following.

1. Created a separate VPC and a subnet
2. Created an Internet Gateway : `igw-03....e..1..d2`
3. Configured Route table to

```
Destination Target Status Propagated
10.0.0.0/24 local   Active  No
<my ip>/32  igw-03....e..1..d2  Active  No
```

4. Created security group to allow all traffic from my ip to the machine.

Used these above, VPC, subnet and Security group while creating the Elastic Beanstalk env. I think I need some way for the AWS services to complete access over my instance.
(Clearly) I am new to AWS and AWS network configs.

Comment: You just need an inbound rule in the security group that allows your IP address, and no other inbound rules. There is no other changes need to the default VPC subnet, route table, etc. It sounds like perhaps you removed the default *outbound* security group rule that allows the EC2 instance to make outbound network requests.